# SQL Server backup Using Windows command line

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-server-2003

My Windows Server 2003 got corrupted and I'm trying to repair it but before that I'm trying to create a backup of my SQL Server databases.

Can anyone please tell me which files do I need to copy from the Windows command line as I'm not familiar with SQL Server. Database files from which I can restore data.

Its an old server but data is important.

And also if I repair Windows server 2003 using repair disk will it effect on SQL Server files ?

http://postimg.org/image/5jsstbqmd/

When I start server I get this error.

Comment: The best way would be to do the backup **in SQL Server** itself - copying out the data and structure into a `.bak` file for each database. Just fiddling around with the data files isn't the preferred way to go .... (might end up being in a non-recoverable state)

Comment: Does SQL server work? Does the server boot at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this SQL command (adapt to your specific case):

```
--Back up the files in SalesGroup1:
BACKUP DATABASE YourDBName
   TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\BackupFileName.bck';
GO
```

See [Backup in Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) for more details.

To run a SQL script from command line:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Before messing with anything, you could take a complete image of your hard drive using a tool such as [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org).

Answer (score 0):

I would get to the root of your disk and run

```
dir /a /s *.mdf
```

The `.mdf` file is the file extension that SQL Server uses, and that command will tell you where they are located. The log files are usually in the same directory.

As per your second question, the disk repair will only affect your database files if they are part of the corruption that is happening; which is quite likely if you were running a high I/O database when it crashed. I would definitely try and copy those files off before running a disk check.

Comment: And while you're at it - please also include the `.ldf` (transaction log file) and `.ndf` (secondary data) files !!